The mobile terminal Chorme enters the same URL in the address bar, resulting in inconsistent window.innerHeight obtained
In the mobile Chorme, when I opened this URL from the homepage for the first time, the whole web page looked normal.
At this time, the website has been opened, then click the address bar above the chorme, then paste the URL in, and click the search of the soft keyboard. At this time, innerHeight is abnormal. At this time, you only need to click on the screen to return to normal, and the resize event will be triggered.
img
img
img
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <script>

    </script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            height: 100svh;
        }

        .a {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            border: 2px solid #ff00ff;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
        }

        .b {
            position: fixed;
            top: 5.5%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .c {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 5.5%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="a">
        <h1 id="a1" style="margin-top: 300px;"></h1>
        <div class="b"><button>123</button></div>
        <div class="c"><button>456</button></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function appHeight() {
            const e = document.documentElement;
            let el = document.getElementById('a1')
            el.innerText = window.innerHeight
            e.style.setProperty("--vh", .01 * window.innerHeight + "px")
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize", appHeight), appHeight();


    </script>
</body>

</html>

I'm very confused now.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
